# Laravel eager loading relation with condition on model properties

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, relation

I have a relation that has a `where` condition based on one of the properties of the main model.

```php
// Product model
public function optionValues() {
        $relation = $this->hasMany(ProductOptionValue::class);

        if ($this->stock_status_id == Product::CustomStock) {
            return $relation->where('status', 1);
        }

        return $relation
            ->where('price', '>', 0)
            ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
            ->where('status', 1);
}
```

I try to find a product with eager loaded relations like this:

```php
Product::with([..., 'optionValues'])->find($productId);
```

but when the code reaches the relation function, `$this` has no properties.

so always `$this->stock_status_id` is null and condition does not work.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I would use a `getVariableNameAttribute` function rather than using if statements in a relationship function.

Comment: @GertB. Can you be a little bit more specific on how to use `getVariableNameAttribute` instead of `where`?

Comment: Well you should never use `$this->model_attribute` in a relationship function. with the function I suggest you can add custom attributes to a model, or change existing ones. Another option is to define 2 relationships.